# avoid casting with different game types

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, casting, coding-style

Hey i am building a framework for the creation of reel games, but in my framwork different game types can be added, not only reelgames. For example, the main game is a reel game and the bonus game is a roulette game. In my framework there is now a main class that holds all games. The user of the framework can decide for himself which game is a main game or a bonus game.

The parent class of both games is "Game", the class of the reel game is "ReelGame" and the class of the roulette game is "RouletteGame". My class that holds all games has a list with "Game".

If I now want to access a game with GetGame(...), a "Game" class is returned and I would have to cast the "Game" to a "ReelGame" or "RouletteGame" to access "Slot" in the "ReelGame" or "Table" in the "RouletteGame". Is there a way to prevent this?

I hope it is explained reasonably well :D thanks for any ideas

here is a short example

```
public class Game
{
   protected int _id;
   protected GameStateMachine _gameStateMachine;
}

public class ReelGame:Game
{
   public Slot Slot;
}

public class RouletteGame:Game
{
   public Table Table;
}

public class GameController:
{
   private List<Game> _mainGames;
   private List<Game> _bonusGames;

   public Game GetGame(int type, int index)
   {
      if(type == 0)
      {
         return _mainGame[index];
      }
      else if(type == 1)
      {
         return _bonusGames[index];
      }
   }
}

private Foo()
{
   ((ReelGame)gameController.GetGame(0, 0)).Slot // how to avoid
}
```

Comment: "a `Game` class is returned to me and I would have to cast the `Game` again and again"  - why???? If it is already of type `Game` why would you need to cast it to `Game`? Very confusing - please consider to [edit] the post to clarify.

Comment: I hope it is now clearer

Comment: When you say "again and again", are you saying that you will have to cast each item once or that you will have to cast each item multiple times? If you mean the former, of course you do. If you mean the latter, no you don't.

Answer (score 1):

The general way to avoid casting is to ensure there is a common interface, so you can call methods on the base type instead of doing any casting. But this require that classes are designed so there is a common interface.

When designing your class hierarchy you usually want to use somewhat abstract concepts rather than mapping real world concepts to classes. So what are the commonalities between both games? Presumably they both have a start and end, they have some type of graphics, some way for the user to control the game, and they might have some type of scoring.

So when you want to start a specific game you should not do any casting to gain access to slots, or anything else. Instead you should tell the graphics system to draw graphics for the selected game, redirect input to the selected game, etc. All of the actual game logic should be inside the game.

If you need to separate some functionality from the actual game you can use the [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

Note that dividing functionality into cohesive classes and modules is one of the most difficult problems in programming. You will almost certainly make mistakes that you only realize much later. Experience and looking how others have solved similar problems can help.